# How can I validate form client-side with this naming convention

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a form that has some simple javascript to validate a simple questionnaire. It used the name attribute on inputs in the form but now the page is integrated with the clients CMS it needs to use a particular naming convention which I can't get to work.

The old form had inputs like this:
`<input type="text" name="firstName" />`

but with the cms all fields require `"fields[firstName]"`, e.g.: 
`<input name="fields[first-name]">`

How do I get this to work.

Exisiting JS below:

```
function validate_form ( )
{
    valid = true;

    if ( ( document.register.question[0].checked == false ) && ( document.register.question[1].checked == false ) && ( document.register.question[2].checked == false ) )
    {
        alert ( "Please choose an answer" );
        valid = false;
    }

    else if ( document.register.form_title.value == "" )
    {
        alert ( "Please fill in the 'Title' box." );
        valid = false;
    }

    else if ( document.register.fName.value == "" )
    {
        alert ( "Please add your First Name" );
        valid = false;
    }

    else if ( document.register.lName.value == "" )
    {
        alert ( "Please add your Last Name" );
        valid = false;
    }

    else if ( document.register.email.value == "" )
    {
        alert ( "Please add a valid email address" );
        valid = false;
    }

    else if ( document.register.country.selectedIndex == 0 )
    {
        alert ( "Please select your Country" );
        valid = false;
    }

    else if ( document.register.dob1.selectedIndex == 0 )
    {
        alert ( "Please ensure your date of birth is complete" );
        valid = false;
    }
    else if ( document.register.dob2.selectedIndex == 0 )
    {
        alert ( "Please ensure your date of birth is complete" );
        valid = false;
    }
    else if ( document.register.dob3.selectedIndex == 0 )
    {
        alert ( "Please ensure your date of birth is complete" );
        valid = false;
    }

    else if ( document.register.terms.checked == false )
    {
        alert ( "Please check the Terms & Conditions box." );
        valid = false;
    }


    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery with something like this:

```
$("input[name=fields\\[first-name\\]]").val()
```